# Is it possible to convert ISO8859-1 encoded text feed to UTF-8 before displaying using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

I embedded a short script into a client's website which is grabbing text feed content from a 3rd party. The result is 5 links encoded in ISO8859-1. Since the whole website has UTF-8 French content, this feed is creating artifacts.

Is there any way to use JavaScript / jQuery to convert the ISO feed to UTF and then display everything on the website properly?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The solution in my case was actually easy. All I have done was to add `charset='ISO8859-1'` into the JavaScript that was pulling news feed. I hope this will help someone.

Comment: I found [this](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html) from webtoolkit. I am not sure what encoding the input string is in, but they had a [demo](http://www.webtoolkit.info/demo/javascript-utf-8) where you can test your encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Add `charset='ISO8859-1'` into the JavaScript that pulls the news feed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got the solution down pat.

Javascript internally uses UTF-16 (I think) on most systems. So when you are importing data from a feed, you need to make sure and tell it what character set to expect so that it will properly decode into Javascript's internals. This can be done in various ways, but is easiest done by having the feed properly declare its character encoding using headers/XML. Then, the browser will usually handle the details for getting things onto the page so that they display correctly in the page's encoding.

I have found a few edge cases that were difficult to deal with, but largely, this just works as long as you make sure everybody knows what encoding the feed is using as it comes in.